# How to input search icon in a search box using font awesome

Tags: reactjs

I have a search box and in this search box, I want to input the search icon using font awesome which I have added the CDN at the index file of my react application

I have installed font awesome using the CLI and I have added the font awesome code to the search box but I keep getting the response font awesome not defined.

```
    div className="header">
      <p>Hello World</p> 
      <span>Clients list</span>
      <input 
       className="form-control" 
       type="search"
       placeholder = "search"/> 
       <FontAwesomeIcon icon="search"/>

   </div>
```

I just want the search icon to show right beside the search word in the placeholder and also within the search box.

Comment: How did you import `FontAwesome`?

Comment: You need to add an import to the top of any page you'll use it, it's not enough just to add it into your index, it needs to be in scope

Comment: import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'; This was how I added the import statement